# How to fill background color in ant-design charts with y-axis value condition

Tags: reactjs, charts, ant-design-pro

So I'm currently using ant-design charts to plot data which I pull from Django to React. What I wanna do is to fill colors to the background according to the y-axis values. For eg, I want the background color for 15-18 to be red, 18-20 to be yellow, 20-25 to be green and so on and so forth. Here's a screenshot of what I want to achieve: [image: Expected Result]

and what I have so far is a very simple Line chart:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Line } from "@ant-design/charts";

const Graph = (props) => {
  var config = {
    data: props.data,
    padding: "auto",
    xField: "Hour",
    yField: "Measurement",
    yAxis: {
      minLimit: 15,
      maxLimit: 30,
      tickCount: 16,
    },
  };
  return <Line {...config} />;
};

export default Graph;
```

I've tried finding articles or guides online but is unable to find any. Any help would be appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Region annotations
https://g2plot.antv.vision/en/docs/api/plots/tiny-area#-region-annotation

```
var config = {
 ...
 annotations: [
   {
     type: 'region',
     start: ['min', 15]
     end: ['max', 18],
     style: {
       fill: '#ff0000'
     }
   },
   {
     type: 'region',
     start: ['min', 18]
     end: ['max', 20],
     style: {
       fill: '#00ffff'
     }
   }
   ...
 ]
}
```